# How to remove Duplicate xml-nodes and to retain only one of the duplicate entries in the output

Tags: xml, xslt

My Input is :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <MDMInput>
        <Input>
            <WileyProductCategory>PJ</WileyProductCategory>
            <FullfilmentType>subscription</FullfilmentType>
            <Frequency/>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <WileyProductCategory>EJ</WileyProductCategory>
            <FullfilmentType>onetime</FullfilmentType>
            <Frequency/>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <WileyProductCategory>EJ</WileyProductCategory>
            <FullfilmentType>subscription</FullfilmentType>
            <Frequency/>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <WileyProductCategory>EJ</WileyProductCategory>
            <FullfilmentType>subscription</FullfilmentType>
            <Frequency/>
        </Input>
    </MDMInput>
</root>
```

Desired Output is :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <MDMInput>
        <Input>
            <WileyProductCategory>PJ</WileyProductCategory>
            <FullfilmentType>subscription</FullfilmentType>
            <Frequency/>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <WileyProductCategory>EJ</WileyProductCategory>
            <FullfilmentType>onetime</FullfilmentType>
            <Frequency/>
        </Input>
        <Input>
            <WileyProductCategory>EJ</WileyProductCategory>
            <FullfilmentType>subscription</FullfilmentType>
            <Frequency/>
        </Input>
    </MDMInput>
</root>
```

In Input XML the 2 of the Input nodes have same values for 'WileyProductCategory' and 'FullfilmentType'.
My requirement is to remove all such duplicate tags and keep only one of the duplicate tag.

Kindly help.
Niharika

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're much more likely to get good responses to questions on Stack Overflow if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem.  Not showing your work gives the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with a variation on the standard "Muenchian grouping" technique - define a *key* that groups together `Input` elements that share the same child values

```
<xsl:key name="inputGroup" match="Input"
   use="concat(WileyProductCategory, '|', FullfilmentType)" />
```

then given a particular category/type pair you can determine the *first* element in the document that has this key value using

```
key('inputGroup', concat(WileyProductCategory, '|', FullfilmentType))[1]
```

To tie it together we start with an "identity" transformation (which copies the input to the output unchanged unless you override it with more specific templates), and then add a template to ignore all but the first element in each group.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="inputGroup" match="Input"
     use="concat(WileyProductCategory, '|', FullfilmentType)" />

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore second and subsequent elements in each key group -->
  <xsl:template match="Input[generate-id() != generate-id(key('inputGroup',
          concat(WileyProductCategory, '|', FullfilmentType))[1])]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here `generate-id()` is the unique identifier for the `Input` element the template is trying to match, and `generate-id(key(....)[1])` is the unique identifier of the first element in the document that matches the same key value.